# What is this bushy, lemony, red-flowering herb?

Tags: identification, herbs

Can you help me identify this plant?

It is about a foot tall.

It has a slightly lemony smell. I don't think it's a mint.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Lantana camara to me, an herbaceous perennial (but half hardy in cooler regions like Britain) which is toxic if ingested.

Comment: You could add that the changing colors or the individual blossoms are quite distinctive.

Comment: This seems to be it, thank you very much! We did taste a couple leaves, really grateful for the information (and will be more careful in the future)